# Posting a login request to a website to scrape data in C#

Tags: c#, http-post

I want to log in to my school's website using C# to scrape some data, but I'm unsure about how to do it. Url: https://www.lectio.dk/lectio/31/default.aspx (the "log ind" will take you to the login-screen).

So I've tried quite a lot of stuff, but my understanding is that I should firstly do a GET to store some cookies for an eventual POST containing the login information. When the POST is complete my HTTPClient should be able to make http requests to get information. I'm not sure I've understood/executed it correctly though. Here's my code.

```
var baseAdress = new Uri("https://www.lectio.dk/lectio/31/");
            var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer, UseCookies = true})
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAdress })
            {
                var homePageResult = client.GetAsync("login.aspx");
                homePageResult.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {


                    //information hidden for privacy reasons
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("m%24Content%24username2","username"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("m%24Content%24passwordHidden", "password"),

                });
                var loginResult = client.PostAsync("login.aspx", content).Result;
                loginResult.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                //'forside' means frontpage in danish
                Stream responseStream = client.GetStreamAsync("forside.aspx").Result;
                using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

                }
            }
```

I'm expecting to see the response from the actual https://www.lectio.dk/lectio/31/forside.aspx, which is only accessible by loggin in, but it seems the POST doesn't manage to login, so that i only get the response from the /login.aspx.

Comment: Thats because you havent read that the form uses GET to send the variables

Comment: Are you refering to the FormUrlEncodedContet? If so, where can I read that?

Comment: open the source of the page,  there seem to be a number of other variables its expecting you to send too

Comment: Thank you for the help, but what "other variables" do you mean?

Comment: The ones in the html form on the page